# Relation between an equation coefficients and equations's solutions

Tags: parametric

Let consider a second degree
$$a(k)x^2+b(k)x+c(k)=0$$

Suppose I want to find conditions on $k$ so that, called $x_1$ and $x_2$ the two solutions of the equation, they satisfy the following

$$\frac{1}{x_1^2}
+\frac{1}{x_2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Could you give hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We have:

\begin{cases}
 x_1 +x_2 =  -\frac{b(k)}{a(k)} \\
x_1x_2 =\frac{c(k)}{a(k)} 
\end{cases}

and
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4} &= \frac{1}{x_1^2} +\frac{1}{x_2^2}\\ &= \frac{x_1^2 +x_2^2}{x_1^2x_2^2}\\ &=  \frac{(x_1 +x_2)^2-2x_1x_2}{x_1^2x_2^2}
\end{align}